# Write numbers to multiple files

Tags: command-line, files

I want to write the numbers 1-10 to two different files.
I guess I should use the for loop to both print to the files and count from 1 to 10 as it loops but I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count to 10:

```
seq 10
```

Write to two files:

```
tee file1 >file2
```

(Without the `>`, `tee` writes to the two files and additionally to its standard output, i.e. to the terminal unless redirected.)

Count to 10 and write the output to two files:

```
seq 10 | tee file1 >file2
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a *for loop*, you use the loop counter to write the number.

```
for (i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i)
    fprintf(file1,"%d\n", i);
```

A complete example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    file1 = fopen("file1.txt","w");
    file2 = fopen("file2.txt","w");

    int MAX = 10;

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(file1,"%d\n", i);
        fprintf(file2,"%d\n", i);
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}
```